# Perform export on unix from cgi page

Tags: perl, unix, cgi

I am not at all proficient in unix or perl or cgi or apache but have been assigned to find a way to set an environment variable on unix from a cgi web page.

I can successfully set the Environment variable

$ENV{PROGPATH}=$Data{PROGPATH};

But when a 4ge program is launched and then itself launches another program, this variable seems to 'go away'. I think I need to run the command

export PROGPATH;

To make it 'stick' for the second program.

I can't seem to find a way to do this successfully from the cgi page that launches the first  program.

Comment: Something like `system("export $PROGPATH");` perhaps?

Comment: Actually abiessu, that works. I will mark it as a fix if you answer with this. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Perl, the `system` command executes any given command intended for the command line.  Here, it is necessary to `export $PROGPATH` and so the full command would be

```
system("export $PROGPATH");
```

Note that this might leave your system vulnerable to various attacks, so you may want to ensure that `$PROGPATH` gets sanity checked prior to this call.

Answer (score 1):

Simple to do:

```
$ENV{FOO}=1;

system('echo FOO=$FOO');
```

When Perl runs system, it exports the variables to the forked process.